# Entity Framework 6 code-first relations with Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship, ef-fluent-api

I have 3 related tables in an existing database. 
Many-to-Many (Many Person Many Group) and a table between - Event, witch ralate these two tables.

```
public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string No { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    }
   public class Event
    {
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public string EventData { get; set; }
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
        public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
   }

   public class Group
    {
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Event> PersonGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

I ddescribed relations using Fluent API.
First I declared PK's

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
.HasKey(k => k.PersonID });

modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
.HasKey(k => k.EventID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
.HasKey(k => k.GroupID });
```

Now foreign keys:
Person has many Events

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
.HasKey(k => k.PersonID })
.HasMany(k => k.Events)
.WithRequired()
.HasForeignKey(f => f.PersonID);
```

In Event class I have Person (and all its parameters)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
.HasRequired(s => s.Person)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(fk => fk.PersonID);
```

Also I need a Group with all data:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
.HasOptional(s => s.Group)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(fk => fk.GroupID });
```

At least I need a Person group participating in an Event

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
.HasKey(k =>k.GroupID })
.HasMany(k => k.PersonGroup)
.WithOptional()
.HasForeignKey(fk => fk.GroupID);
```

It seems I have everything I need, but I need one mo collection (Group of persons with their names)

What I get through PersonGroup relation I have all events but also need to get Persons. Could You help?

Comment: Most likely you have to revise your model instead of asking how to get information out of the current model. I realized this while refining my answer and included some thoughts into it.

Comment: I am not able to change model... just need to get information ...

Comment: So I am looking for how to get related data without selecting :) And these relations I am trying to put myself

Comment: What do you mean by "related data without selecting"? Your data model won't support a `Group.People` collection without any kind of select. Asking for a result *without technique XY* is a rather strange thing under most circumstances.

Comment: For example, if I need to have Events in a list, I only write: var events =  DBContext.Persons.Events.ToList(); So I wanted to set relations between tables to get at once PersonGroup collection

Comment: Actually, if ` DBContext.Persons` is a `DbSet<Person>`, you __can not__ write `var events = DBContext.Persons.Events.ToList();`, it will give you a compiler error.

Comment: ok ok, I find exactly one event from my DBContext, then I take GroupID from it then find Group entry by this GroupID and take PersonGroup Collection

Comment: var groupCollection = GroupItem.PersonGroup; var personList = groupCollection.Select(n=> n.Person).ToList();

Comment: So I was looking the way to take this list from relations, not bu writing .Select... do You know what I mean?

Comment: I know what you mean and it's not happening with your current model. Even if you had an EF managed many-many relation, EF would internally still create an intermediate table and then join the tables together. By making this intermediate table explicit (`Event`) you no longer allow EF to manage this automatically, so you have to join the tables by hand. The only thing you can do is creating some client-side syntactic sugar - maybe that's all you need, gonna edit the answer a bit.

Comment: This is the answer I needed, that it's not happening with my current model, so I will write all these select statments to get the wanted list :)

Comment: See my edit for client side convenience property

Comment: And what is PersonsInGroupEvents ??

Comment: Its a property name (use any name you want) and its getter result will be the enumerable of person that are related to the group via event.

Comment: I am not lucky to write correct syntax.... only errors

Comment: Compile time errors or runtime errors? Depending on your actual EF usage, you can get many different exceptions like `NullReferenceException` when `PersonGroup` is not initialized or in case of proxies an `ObjectDisposedException` when trying to lazy-load a property. This can happen with my proposed solution, but it's not directly related.

Comment: Acctually it is not even compile errors.. I am not very good in c# (begginer) so everything is ok with model, need a correct syntax for[NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Person> PersonsInGroupEvents
    {
        return PersonGroup.Select(ev => ev.Person);
    }

Comment: It 's my problem and now I am trying to get set correctly :) Thank You a lot for Your help!!

Comment: I am used to work with PL/SQL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I just realize it's not a typical many-to-many, since your Event-Group relation is optional. Is this intended?

Maybe your model should be changed to reflect a more natural event structure:

Group-Person: many-to-many

Event-Group: many-to-many

Event-Person: no direct relation, only via groups; alternative many-to-many

The way your model is currently designed, a single event entry can't be related to more than one group and one person and a person can't be part of a group unless they are associated in the context of an event entry.

---

Basically, the thing you ask for is not directly available, because you decided to explicitely create the many-to-many table with additional properties.

However, in queries you can always write a select to get the persons collection

```
db.Groups.Select(g => new {Group = g, PeopleInGroup = g.PersonGroup.Select(ev => ev.Person)})
```

Few side-notes regarding your model:

- Consider removing `EventID` and instead use `modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().HasKey(k => new { k.PersonID, k.GroupID })`, like a typical many-to-many table would be designed.
- Mention reverse properties in fluent api:

.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
.HasKey(k => k.PersonID })
.HasMany(k => k.Events)
.WithRequired(e => e.Person)
.HasForeignKey(f => f.PersonID);

// redundant with the previous configuration
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
.HasRequired(s => s.Person)
.WithMany(p => p.Events)
.HasForeignKey(fk => fk.PersonID);

// same to be done for groups
```

In order to have a convenient access to the associated people of a group, you could create a not-mapped property getter which wraps the necessary query:

```
public class Group
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> PersonGroup { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Person> PersonsInGroupEvents
    {
        return PersonGroup.Select(ev => ev.Person);
    }
}

// or fluent api way of NotMapped:
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .Ignore(x => x.PersonsInGroupEvents);
```

Comment: So if it is not directly available, I am going to use : db.Groups.Select(g => new {Group = g, PeopleInGroup = g.PersonGroup.Select.....

Comment: @Songaila Note, if you are only interested in the people collection, you don't have to write the `new {...}` part, this is only relevant for creating a relation between group and associated people. Also, you can use grouping or other lookup techniques instead of select if you prefer so. This answer shows a way to find the person collection for given group entries, thats all.